# not possible to install mate desktop

Tags: mate

when trying to install mate desktop, after running command :

```
sudo apt-get install mate-core
```

I get a message that I have held broken packages.

How can I solve the problem?

Current answer in Ubuntu is not solving the issue.

Comment: Is it snowlinux mate?

Answer (score 0):

**Mate Desktop** can be installed with following :

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.mate-desktop.org/repo/ubuntu [UBUNTU VERSION] main"

sudo apt-get install mate-archive-keyring

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mate-core

sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment
```

** Replace `[UBUNTU VERSION]` with your Ubuntu version. Ex: `saucy`,`raring` etc.